# The equation has a solution iff $(k,q-1)=1$

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory

Let $p^n$, where $p$ is a prime, and $k \in \mathbb{N}$. Let $a$ the generator of the cyclic group $\mathbb{F}_p^{\star}$, where $\mathbb{F}_q$ the finite field with $q=p^n$ elements. Show that the equaction $x^k-a=0$ has a root in $\mathbb{F}_q$ if and only if $(k,q-1)=1$.

I have done the following:

$$(k, q-1)=1\Leftrightarrow \lambda k+\mu (q-1)=1\Leftrightarrow b^{\lambda k}\cdot (b^{q-1})^{\mu}=b\Leftrightarrow b^{\lambda k}=b\Leftrightarrow (b^{\lambda })^k-b=0$$

Is this correct??

Comment: you mean $b = a$?

Comment: @Krish I meant $x^k-a=0$. $b$ is an element of $\mathbb{F}_q$.

Comment: $b$ is not just any element of $F_q.$ look at the last expression: $(b^{\lambda})^k - \bf{b}$ $ = 0.$ in the "bold" part you need $a.$

Comment: Could we not set $a=b$ ?? @Krish

Comment: yes. that's what I asked in my first comment. we can take $b = a.$

Comment: So, is it correct?? @Krish

Comment: it looks fine to me. :)

Comment: Great!! Thank you very much!! :-) @Krish